# Show that a Bilinear form is Coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bilinear-form

I'm reading through Brezis' book on functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and PDE, and I'm having trouble showing that the Bilinear form: $a(u,v) = \int_{0}^{2}u'v'dx+\left(\int_{0}^{1}u dx\right) \left(\int_{0}^{1}v dx\right)$
is coercive.(Problem 8.25 #2).

The book offers the following hint:
(Argue by contradiction and assume that there is a sequence $(u_n)$ in $H^1$ such that $a(u_n,u_n)\rightarrow 0$ and $||u_n||_{H^1}=1$. Let $(u_{n_k})$ be a subsequence such that $u_{n_k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $H^1$ and $||u_{n_k}||_{L^2}\rightarrow||u||_{L^2}$ for some limit u. Show that u=0.

From the previous question I have:

$|a(u,v)|\leq ||u||_{H^1}||v||_{H^1}~~~~~~~$     and $~~~~~~~a(u,u)=0 ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ u=0$

I've been throwing ideas at this for most of today and I've failed to come up with anything leading to the contradiction. Any suggestions for the right place to start?

Comment: Just a question (since I know you liked your answer).  But did you mean $H^1(0,2)$?  And what boundary conditions?  If you had meant $H^1(\mathbb R)$, surely a function supported on $[4,5]$ would be a counterexample.  But if you mean Direchlet boundary conditions, then once we knew $u$ is constant, the problem would be done, and the answer could be much shorter.  So it is not obvious to me what you missed out in stating the question.

Comment: I did mean $H^1(0,2)$, the question doesn't supply boundary conditions. Actually its a multi-part question,  the 4th part asks you to determine the equation and boundary conditions satisfied by u.

What I had missed in my attempts was noting that both $\int_0^2 u_n'^2$ and $\int_0^1u_n$ go to zero individually. After that pretty simple bit it kinda fell together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose ad absurdum that there is a sequence $u_n\in H^1$ such that $$a(u_n,u_n)\to 0,\ \ \|u_n\|_{H^1}=1$$

In other words $$\tag{1} \int_0^2 |u_n'|^2+\left(\int_0^1 u_n\right)^2\to 0,\ \int_0^2u_n^2+\int_0^2|u_n'|^2=1$$

We conclude from $(1)$ that $$\int_0^2 |u'_n|\to 0,\ \int_0^2u_n^2\to 1\tag{2}$$

Assume without loss of generality that $u_n\rightharpoonup  u$ in $H^1$, hence, $u_n'\rightharpoonup u'$ in $L^2$ which implies that $$\|u'\|_{L^2}\leq\liminf \|u'_n\|_{L^2}=0$$

We conclude from the last inequality that $u=c$ where $c$ is a constant. Moreover, because $u_n\to u$ in $L^2$ (compact embedding), we have that $$\int_0^2 u_nf\to\int_0^2 uf,\ \forall \ f\in L^2$$

Take $f$ as the characteristic function of the interval $(0,1)$, hence $$\int_0^1 u_n\to \int_0^1 u\tag{3}$$

We combine $(3)$ and $(1)$ to conclude that $u=0$ in $[0,1]$. Because $u$ is continuous (every function in $H^1(0,2)$ is continuous) we have that $u=0$ in $[0,2]$. To finish the argument, use $(2)$ to conclude that

$$\int_0^1 u^2=1$$

which is an absurd.